# LibXML printing last half of node

Tags: perl, libxml2

got a question about LibXML I hope y'all can help with.

```
[root@server DAI_P2_10mdc]# cat test.pl
#!bin/perl
BEGIN { chomp(my $wd = `pwd`); unshift @INC, "$wd/lib/perl5/5.20.1"; unshift @INC, "$wd/lib/perl5/5.20.1/x86_64-linux"; unshift @INC, "$wd/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.20.1/x86_64-linux"; unshift @INC, "$wd/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.20.1";}

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $TEMPLATE = "DownConvertJobTemplate.xml";

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $ADI_ORIG = $parser->parse_file($TEMPLATE);

foreach my $node ($ADI_ORIG->findnodes('//job/output_group/file_group_settings/destination')) {
    print $node->toString();
}

[root@server DAI_P2_10mdc]#
[root@server DAI_P2_10mdc]# ./test.pl
<destination>
        <uri/>
      </destination>
```

Actual XML file content:

```
<file_group_settings>
  <rollover_interval nil="true"/>
  <destination>
    <uri></uri>
  </destination>
</file_group_settings>
```

Why am I just receiving the last half of `<uri>`?

Comment: Is that really the whole XML file?

Comment: What do you mean the last half?  Do you know that `<uri/>` is just a short form of `<uri></uri>` ?  Your output looks correct if that is your data.

Comment: @Miller, he wrote "last half of `<uri>`", but improper formatting made it show as "last half of ". Fixed.

Comment: "Do you know that <uri/> is just a short form of <uri></uri> ?" : Nope! Thanks for the clarification! I'm new to all of this.

Also, no, that is not the entire XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It didn't write

```
</uri>
```

as you claim. It wrote

```
<uri/>
```

The latter is [equivalent](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) to

```
<uri></uri>
```

You should have no reason to do so, but if you don't like this for whatever odd reason, you can use

```
local $XML::LibXML::setTagCompression = 0;
```

in scope of your call to serialize.